# modifications in content folder won't update in the public folder

Tags: python, pelican

I am new to `Pelican` (one python static site generator) and following tutorial trying to understand the basic parts. I am using `SoMA2` as my theme. But I met with a strange problem and didn't not know what to do.

Here it is.

I created a **about.md** under *pages* folder and generate *html* websites. The *About* page is on the navigation. So far so good. However, if I deleted **about.md** file and run make *html* again, the *About* page is still there, but shouldn't.

I've tried many times and have no idea about that. Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelican does not delete old files by default. However there's a setting you can use:

```
DELETE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = True
```

With this, Pelican **will remove** the output directory every time you generate your site, removing any old files.